# What should the back of my pilot certificate say?

Tags: pilot-certification

I hold an ATP multi engine land rating, as well as a commercial single and multi. But the back of my card says

Airline Transport Pilot

Airplane Multiengine land

Commercial Privileges

Airplane single engine land

Is this right? Should it not say multi and single engine privileges?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you hold an Airline Transport Pilot (ATP) ***certificate***, which means your Commercial Pilot ***certificate*** no longer exists, it has been *superseded*.

The "grade" of your pilot certificate now is Airline Transport Pilot (ATP), not Commercial Pilot.

On your ATP ***certificate*** you hold an Airplane Multiengine Land ***rating***.

Also, on your ATP ***certificate***, you have Commercial ***privileges*** (not a certificate) for Airplane Single-engine Land aircraft.

So, your certificate is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The back of the certificate is correct.  The AMEL moves to the ATP line and the ASEL stays on the Commercial line.  There is no instrument airplane rating as that is removed with the addition of the ATP certificate.

The ATP AMEL stipulates that you can use it for both airline transport and commercial pilot privileges.